# Positive and negative rail for op amp circuit

Tags: power-supply, dc, circuit-design, ac-dc, linear-regulator

I need a positive and negative rail to power an op amp

Since it's an op amp for a voltage reference, would using a circuit like this one be enough?

Input voltage is unregulated 37 volts, with 4.7k resistors; current is about 7.8 milliAmps

[image]

Since the op-amp is needed as the error amp for variable output voltage, the op-amps supply voltage will be unregulated.

Are there any pitfalls that I should be aware about? Any other topology?

Comment: you might be able to get away with it if you use a very low current opamp driving a very high impedance load

Comment: Can you provide details on the voltage reference?

Comment: This is very likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?r=SearchResults&s=1|1217.3904).  Could you please edit your question to show what you really want to do?  If your goal is to provide a steady voltage reference, you may not need a virtual ground at all, given the proper selection of op-amp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest potential issue is that your negative supply is only negative with respect to that wonky quasi-split-supply point and usually that's not what you want in a DC-coupled circuit like a regulator that needs to provide an output and accept an input relative to ground.

It might be okay enough for an AC-coupled (both input and output) amplifier of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Load regulation error, is defined like a filter transfer function by comparing the load to source impedance as a voltage divider.

Choose R< 1% of load impedance  and choose C by noise frequency of load  attenuated by 20dB /decade above break point.

The importance for this is your choice of a 0V reference for the signal input and it's amplified output.

So for example if the signal draws 100uA then 7.8mA 0V reference is adequate and the offset may be small enough.

> It is best to define source Impedance , current or voltage and load of Op Amp when a 0V reference also adds to the source impedance.

- Better virtual ground.
- Instant rise time with two caps (desirable)
- small caps have lower ESR , better for RF.
- low idle current.  (if it matters)
- Near 0 Output impedance up to current limited output.
- less surge current on start to charge 110uF with low ESR

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flfPaU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In these situations with floating unregulated noisy supplies, a good INA Op Amp with balanced signal lines is important for common mode noise rejection.